# Need some function code for checkout

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, checkout

I use my website in my shop on an ipad to process shop orders on an administrators account and i have created a plug in that allows admins to checkout with new options called POS CASH and POS CARD in the shop rather than going through the online merchant bank.

PROBLEM
Each time i process a sale the admin account processing it gets its name, billing details and shipping details overwritten.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION
I think what i need is either some lines of code in the child function .php file or an amended woocemmerce file placed in my child theme.

Im guessing this is a hook on the checkout that updates the user account.

Any help would be grateful. I'm doing lots of changes myself but not confident with messing with hooks.

Thanks Rob

Comment: or perhaps a line of code to not pre fill the customer details on the checkout page if admin is checking out?

Comment: Have an attempt at coding the solution.

Comment: I'm trying. It would help if i knew which file had the source code that updates the customer details. I am right in thinking its class-wc-checkout .php?

Comment: Will this work in my child function php file?   $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); if(is_array($current_user->roles) && in_array('administrator',$current_user->roles)){ add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' ); }

Comment: Yes that should prevent the customer info from being updated.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I’ll give it a go in the morning. I’m a little sceptical because I’m guessing there’s going to be 2 parts to this. The first clearing the pre filled billing and shipping details on the check out form and the second creating an order with the customers details that were entered at check out but then not updating those details on the account which is admin. So I’m guessing the code above does takes care of the second part and I still need to work out the first part.

Comment: You don't need to clear them, just don't update the existing user.  What I have done in the past is just update the user id associated with the new order to move it across to the new user you have created via this update update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', $user_id );

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this the other day for a similar problem I was having placing orders on behalf of customers.  It will create a new customer and assign the order to them but not update the current logged in user's demographics.  I hooked into the thank you page so it will run regardless of if a payment is successful or not.  You can change it to use the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook if you want it to change the order after a successful payment is made.

```
function es_after_setup_theme() {
    /**
     * Ensure customer billing details are not updated if an admin or shop manager is placing an order
     *
     */
    if( es_check_sales_assistant_user() ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );
    }

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'es_after_setup_theme' );

function es_check_sales_assistant_user() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $admin_roles = array( 'administrator', 'shop-manager' );

    if( array_intersect( $admin_roles, $user->roles ) ) { 
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


function es_create_new_customer( $order_id ) {
    if( es_check_sales_assistant_user() ) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        // Create a login for the user and assign the new order to them.
        $email_address = $order->get_billing_email();
        $user_id = email_exists( $email_address );

        // Generate password only letters and numbers
        $random_password = wp_generate_password( 8, false );

        if( ! $user_id ) {
            // Create a new WordPress user, WooCommerce function wc_create_new_customer uses a stipped version of the email address for the username.
            $username = sanitize_user( current( explode( '@', $email_address ) ), true );

            // Ensure username is unique.
            $append     = 1;
            $o_username = $username;

            while ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
                $username = $o_username . $append;
                $append++;
            }

            $userdata = array(
                'user_login'    => $username,
                'user_pass'     => $random_password,
                'user_email'    => $email_address,
                'first_name'    => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
                'last_name'     => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
                'role'          => 'customer',
            );

            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

            if( $user_id ) {
                // Add WooCommerce billing details
                $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

                $customer->set_billing_first_name( $order->get_billing_first_name() );
                $customer->set_billing_last_name( $order->get_billing_last_name() );
                $customer->set_billing_address_1( $order->get_billing_address_1() );
                $customer->set_billing_city( $order->get_billing_city() );
                $customer->set_billing_postcode( $order->get_billing_postcode() );
                $customer->set_billing_state( $order->get_billing_state() );
                $customer->set_billing_country( $order->get_billing_country() );
                $customer->set_billing_phone( $order->get_billing_phone() );
                $customer->set_billing_email( $email_address );

                $customer->save();
            }
        }

        // Update order to new customer id
        $order->set_customer_id( $user_id );
        $order->save();
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'es_create_new_customer' );
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew this works really well but something weird is going on. I created an admin user account with no name or details and use this account to process shop orders. I processed an order and sure enough it created a new account and assigned the order to it. I checked the admin account and it remained unchanged. All good. Then i process a second order and the billing address and shipping address is showing at the checkout for the previous order which is weird because that info isnt on the user account and there are no orders on the user account. I'm thinking cache or browser cache?

Comment: It's probably something to do with your browser cache as I haven't experience this.

Comment: I’ll try it on a few different devices and browsers. It may even be an auto fill feature. I’m using chrome on windows.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it auto fills my administrator demographics only.  There's a hook to remove it from defaulting values but in your case it's getting them from the browser it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on the browser and no luck other than clearing the shopping basket, logging out and closing the browser, logging back in and then and only then the form cleared. Very strange. In the end i slightly adapted your code with the second add filter and this clears everything after the order is made. Thank you so much for your help Andrew. Really appreciated it :D

```
if( es_check_sales_assistant_user() ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string',10);
}
```